# Linear Layout not handle clicks

Tags: android

I have such fragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addNewItem"
    android:clickable="true">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addCityCityNameEdit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/cityNameEditHint"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/defaultMargin"
        android:clickable="false" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/addCityButton"
        android:id="@+id/addCityButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/defaultMargin" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cityListRecycleView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And problem with my layout "addNewItem". I need to response to click the Layout space, but nothing happen when I click. Code in fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_list_fragment, container, false);
    addNewView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.addNewItem);
    addNewView.setAlpha(0.6f);
    addNewView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked");
        }
    });
    .........
```

What's wrong? My layout have cliclable=true, but it's not respond to my clicks. 
I want to implement this view in way that at first it's children disabled(setEnabled(false)). And when user long click on LinearLayout it "unlock" its childs and then user can add item in recycler view via this unlocked editText and add button.

Comment: try setting `android:focusable="true"` too. Or use the `android:onclick` Event

Comment: or give the id on the first LinearLayout

Comment: I tried this methods(id to root layout, focusable and onclick), but problem is still here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/addNewItem"
                android:clickable="true">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dummyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addCityCityNameEdit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/cityNameEditHint"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/defaultMargin"
        android:clickable="false" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/addCityButton"
        android:id="@+id/addCityButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/defaultMargin" />
</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cityListRecycleView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Then in your activity:

```
    findViewById(R.id.dummyView).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Since you would now be in a relative layout, the first child lies above the others and would capture the click events until its visibility is set to gone (done in the onlongclicklistener). You still need to change the way the views are set in the relative layout, but should be easy now (you could also nest another linear layout in there to avoid that, not sure it is a very good practice though).

**Original answer:**
The height is taken completely by the ImageButton and EditText, are the click event not captured even when you click on the "side" of these two views?

You could set the onClickListener to these two views and handle from there too.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_list_fragment, container, false);
addNewView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.addNewItem);
view.findViewById(R.id.addCityCityNameEdit).setOnClickListener(this);
view.findViewById(R.id.addCityButton).setOnClickListener(this);
addNewView.setAlpha(0.6f);
addNewView.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Log.d(TAG, "clicked");
}
.........
```

Comment: Is there a way that the container can process clicking on its children(space).
I want to implement this view in way that at first it's children disabled(setEnabled(false). And when user long click on LinearLayout it "unlock" its childs and then user can add item in recycler view via this unlocked editText and add button.

Comment: Which one? I receive notification about comment that begin as "So basicly what you could do...", but it's not visible here. I ask the question for the first time and perhaps missing something

Comment: Added new stuff to my first answer :)

Comment: I figured out, I apologize for the inattention

Comment: You absolutely right about child space and this method works as I expected. I also found interesting topic about touch event interception, thanks to the tip.
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html